# Error using Publish-AzureRmApiManagementTenantGitConfiguration - The authorization server cannot be deleted because it assigned to at least one API

Tags: git, azure-api-management

I am synchronizing our APIM code from our company GIT to the APIM instance GIT. This all seems to be going well.

When I run:

```
$PsApiManagementOperationResult = Publish-zureRmApiManagementTenantGitConfiguration -Context $context -Branch "master" -Force -PassThru -Verbose
```

I get the following error:
[image]

> The authorization server cannot be deleted because it assigned to at least one API.

I can't seem to find out any more information. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution for this was to remove the OAuth 2.0 setting I had attached to one of my APIs. I then was able to deploy and my code I was deploying put back the OAuth 2.0 with the correct Authorization server.